# How to alias an export in bash

Tags: bash, export, alias

I am trying to set an env variable which I can use to do relative directory chains. I am trying to do it the following way but cant get it to work. How do I do it?

```
alias sroot="export SROOT="$PWD""
alias drumit="cd $SROOT/abc/def/drumit"
```

If I type sroot, it takes the alias but when i type drumit, it gives me an error saying

```
bash: cd: /abc/def/drumit: No such file or directory
```

Looks like when the shell was launched it takes `$SROOT` as `.`
Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of the `pushd` and `popd` builtins? You might construct your aliases from those.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your $PWD and $SROOT variables are being expanded at the time you define the aliases, not when you are using them. Put a \ in front of them to escape them while they are defined.

```
alias sroot="export SROOT="\$PWD""
alias drumit="cd \$SROOT/abc/def/drumit"
```

Comment: By the way, i dont understand how the escape sequence can help here. But it did. Can you please explain a little? Thanks

Comment: This solution worked for zsh running Oh-my-zshell in iTerm2.lol

Answer (score 2):

When you initially set the alias, it expands `$PWD` instead of keeping it as the variable form.  Try using `function` instead like this:

```
$ function sroot {
> export SROOT="$PWD"
> }
$ export -f sroot
$ function drumit {
> cd $SROOT/cron
> }
$ export -f drumit
$ declare -f sroot
sroot()
{ 
    export SROOT="$PWD"
}
$ declare -f drumit
drumit ()
{
    cd $SROOT/abc/def/drumit
}
```

---

This is what is currently happening when you alias like in your question (variable expanding):

```
$ alias sroot="export SROOT="$PWD""
$ alias drumit="cd $SROOT/abc/def/drumit"
$ alias
alias SROOT='/home/jon'
alias drumit='cd /home/jon/abc/def/drumit'
alias sroot='export SROOT=/home/jon'
```

Escaping would work too:

```
$ alias sroot="export SROOT="\$PWD""
$ alias drumit="cd \$SROOT/abc/def/drumit"
$ alias
alias drumit='cd $SROOT/abc/def/drumit'
alias sroot='export SROOT=$PWD'
```